# Understanding java recursive generic type definitions with type erasion

Tags: java, generics, inheritance

I'm very confused facing this line of code:

```
public abstract class ClassName<T extends ClassName<?>>{}
```

I know what `<T>` is, what `abstract` is, what inheritance is but I just can't summarize all I see in this line.

Please can someone explain in simple words what does that interesting thing means?
**Not a duplicate of questions about `<T>` and `<?>`. The confusing thing here is that `ClasName` appears twice.**
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So `ClassName` has a generic parameter `T` and this parameter needs to fit a certain requirement, in this case extends a certain type `S`, that means, `T` must inherit `S`. Now the interesting thing in this case is this `S`.

We have `S` to be `ClassName<?>`, so `T` must inherit from `ClassName` with a wildcard. For the wildcard aka the question mark please have a look at the link Michael Markidis gave in a comment to your question.

The real fun now is that this definition

```
public abstract class ClassName<T extends ClassName<?>>
```

allows **recursive** generic type defintion. So you could have something like

```
ClassName<ClassName<ClassName<ClassName<?>>>> test;
```

for whatever that's worth :)

**EDIT:** Given

```
ClassName2<T extends ClassName<?>> extends ClassName<T>
```

thats relatively easy in comparison. We want to inherit `ClassName` but not "destroy" the generic argument, so we take one `ClassName` would accept, in this case `T extends ClassName<?>`. In `extends ClassName<T>` the compiler checks if this (i.e. `ClassName2`'s) `T` fits the `T` of `ClassName`, which was the requirement (remember `ClassName`'s definition) `T extends ClassName<?>`, so this obviously works.

In addition, we have `ClassName2<?>` extending `ClassName<?>`, so now you can mix the two types however you want:

```
ClassName2<ClassName<ClassName<ClassName<?>>>> test2;
ClassName2<ClassName<ClassName2<ClassName<?>>>> test3;
```

However, if you would have, say

```
class ClassName3<T extends ClassName3<?>> extends ClassName<T>
```

(the public and abstrac modifiers don't really influence the generic behavior here), you can only have things like

```
ClassName3<ClassName3<ClassName3<ClassName3<?>>>> test4;
ClassName2<ClassName<ClassName3<ClassName3<?>>>> test5;
```

since `ClassName` and `ClassName2`don't inherit `ClassName3`.

Comment: oh, I was afraid to hear the "recursive" in this context ))) Actually next class I have public abstract class ClassName2<T extends ClassName<?>> extends ClassName<T>.

Comment: @Evgeniy Mishustin extended my answer according to your comment :-) I'm glad the Type Erasure hint could help you

Answer (score 4):

`public` means the class is visible to all other classes. 
`abstract` means the class can not be instantiated (you'll have to find a non-abstract subclass for that) 
`inheritance` is an important concept in object-oriented programming. Read a book about OOP or consult wikipedia.

`T extends ClassName<?>` means there is an upper bound put on the type parameter `T`, such that `T` needs to be a subclass of `ClassName<?>`. `?` means unbounded type parameter.

I will provide a little more meaningful example that might make it easier to understand the concept of using bounded recursive type parameters. Lets assume you have a class `Thingy`. You want all subclasses of `Thingy` to be comparable, but just to the same subclass. Ie you want nails to be comparable to nails, but not bikes:

```
interface Thingy<T extends Thingy<T>> extends Comparable<T> {}

class Nail implements Thingy<Nail> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Nail o) { ... }
}

class Bike implements Thingy<Bike> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Bike o) { ... }
}
```

Comment: the confusing thing is how can abstract class be of type class that inherits from it? It sounds like neverending story

Comment: Not really. You just have to look at how a subclass may look... `class Foo extends ClassName<Foo>{}` and `class Bar extends ClassName<Foo>{}` could be two such subclasses...

Comment: @Evgeniy Mishustin That works through Type Erasure, important concept with generics. And yes, the neverending story is the cool thing about that, see my answer. Didn't even know about that possibility before :-D

Comment: *went learning "Type Erasure"* my lecturer missed that part ))

Comment: "You want all subclasses of Thingy to be comparable, but just to the same subclass." But the declaration doesn't do that. In fact, no declaration will do that in Java. You can still have `class Foo implements Thingy<Nail> {
    @Override public int compareTo(Nail o) { ... }
}` The recursive bound is useless in your example.

Comment: @GreenThor: Type erasure has *absolutely nothing* to do with it.

Comment: @newacct https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html As I see it, it does. Maybe I'm just getting the English wrong and maybe my memories of my lectures are a bit blurry, but I'm ready to learn if you can provide a resourceful reference.

Comment: @GreenThor: So, please tell what type erasure has to do with anything here.